# Return first six characters of a binary file

Tags: windows, binary, autocad, windows-explorer

I'm looking for a fast/easy way to return the first six characters of a binary file inside Windows 7. Opening the file in a hex editor to inspect the first few characters is too slow for our use.

Ideally, we'd be able to right click a file to get the first six characters OR, alternatively, be able to add a field to Windows Explorer that would show the first six characters for any file that had a particular file extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can add a custom FirstSixCharacters property for the extension.

Comment: How would I do that? Any resources that can help?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728871(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you want to see the first bytes of files with identical file extensions?